# Cellular structure of BSU(n)

Tags: classifying-spaces, cw-complexes

I read somewhere that $BSU(n)$ has a cellular decomposition that consists of one 4-cell and higher dimensional cells. Can someone tell me why this is the case? In fact I am not sure if this statement is true. For example, $BSU(2)$ is $\mathbb{H}P^\infty$, which I believe has the cellular decomposition $\bigcup_{k=0}^\infty e^{4k}$. In particular, it contains a 0-cell.

Comment: This goes under the name of Schubert cells.

Comment: Are you certain your source deliberately meant to forgo 0-cells, rather than simply assuming but omitting mention of them?

Comment: CW complexes without zero cells are empty, so you are certainly correct that there should be one. But also, maybe the focus is on pointed spaces, in which case we pick that zero cell to be the basepoint, and then the first *relative* cell is in dimension four.

Comment: There's a notion of cell decomposition distinct from that of CW complexes, so there's an outside possibility that this is what was meant, a decomposition of some model of $BSU(n)$ into some union of Euclidean spaces, all of dimension $>4$ (although this would be more of a curiosity than particularly useful).

Comment: Thanks to all. After a second look it does look like that the author neglected to mention the 0-cell, as what he claims later using this fact hold when there is a 0-cell. However, I still don't see why there are no 2-cells for general $n$.

Comment: @jdc What is this other notion of cell decomposition? Can you give some references?

Comment: @DaveBenson Thanks. I only know Schubert calculus for 
the usual complex or real Grassmannians. Presumably $BSU(n)$ is modeled on some Grassmannian of complex "oriented" (fixing a trivialization of the determinant bundle) Grassmannian. Is there also a Schubert decomposition for this version of Grassmannian? Do you know any reference which does this explicitly?